# In game timer Spark AR

Tags: spark-ar-studio

Has anyone figured out how to convert a pulse value into a string, such that I would be able to create a live timer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFbqK.png)

This is my following Patch editor for this issue.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I figured out, were the patch editor is still in use.

```
    Diagnostics.log("Complete!");
    var Timer_Value = Patches.getScalarValue('Timer');
    var Timer_Text = Scene.root.find("Timer").text = Timer_Value.toString();
    AudioBool = false;
    Patches.setBooleanValue('AudioBool', AudioBool);
```

I am using the AudioBool to end the experience.[This is the Patch editor view to start the timer. This is done by activating a boolean value within the script to start the timer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdm0W.png)

Additionally: I might update this answer with a formatted timer like so 00:00.